# Base of intersection

Tags: linear-algebra

I have 2 bases:

$Base(U)={(1,2,3),(2,3,4)}$

$Base(V)={(1,1,2),(2,2,3)}$

And I need to find a Base for the vector room $U∩V$ of dimension 1.

I'd appreciate it if any1 could check my work:

Let $Z\in U∩V$, then $Z=a*(1,2,3)+b*(2,3,4)$ And $Z=-c*(1,1,2)-d*(2,2,3)$

So I make the following:

$a*(1,2,3)+b*(2,3,4)-c*(1,1,2)-d*(2,2,3)=0$ I solve a,b,c and get:

$a=-d, b=d, c=-d$

So is my base: $Base(-1,1,-1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this algorithmically.

Let
\begin{align*}
u_1 &= \langle1,2,3\rangle &
u_2 &= \langle2,3,4\rangle &
v_1 &= \langle1,1,2\rangle &
v_2 &= \langle2,2,3\rangle
\end{align*}
and put these given bases into the columns of two matrices
\begin{align*}
A &=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 3 \\
3 & 4
\end{array}\right] & 
B &=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 \\
2 & 3
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
Note that each of these matrices is rank two so $\dim U=\dim V=2$, as expected.

Then form the augmented matrix
$$
[A\mid B] = 
\left[\begin{array}{rr|rr}
1 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 3 & 1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 & 2 & 3
\end{array}\right]
$$
Row reducing $[A\mid B]$ gives
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref [A\mid B]=
\left[\begin{array}{rr|rr}
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
The rank of this matrix is the dimension of $U+V$. That is, $\dim(U+V)=3$. The [dimension theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dimension_of_Sum_and_Intersection_of_Vector_Spaces) then implies
$$
\dim(U\cap V)=\dim(U)+\dim(V)-\dim(U+V)=2+2-3=1
$$

The row reduction also tells us that
$$
-u_1+u_2+v_1=v_2
$$
That is, the vector $-u_1+u_2=-v_1+v_2$ is in the intersection $U\cap V$. Since $\dim(U\cap V)=1$ we conclude that
$$
U\cap V=\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\{-u_1+u_2\}=\Span\{\langle 1,1,1\rangle\}
$$